# Azure Blob Storage Listing Blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need a functionality for listing blobs from azure such that if I specify date, the list should only contain blobs created after that date.

Currently I am using BlobDirectory.ListBlobs() function which returns all the blobs. It also has a overloaded function which takes BlobRequestOptions as parameter. I have tried setting the AccessCondition in the BlobRequestOptions to AccessCondition.IfModifiedSince(Date.UTC.Now) but somehow it gives me all the blobs stored in the container.

Any suggestion on what I can do differently to get particular subset of blobs

Comment: Are you running this against the storage emulator or against an actual blob container?

Comment: Against the actual blob container on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think AccessCondition would apply to a listing of blobs, just an individual blob itself (though the documentation isn't clear). A quick HTTP trace would confirm whether the associate HTTP header is sent for that call.

If indeed it does apply to the ListBlobs() call, the resource would be the blob container itself.  Therefore, I'd expect it to return either all of the blobs or none of the blobs in the container, depending on whether the container itelf had been modified since the provided date.

Comment: Even if that is the case Date.UTC.Now should not return me any blobs. Yes I agree with you, it seems like the documentation is not updated to reflect that AccessConditions does not seem to apply to ListBlobs.

Answer (score 2):

This article shows getting blobs older than a certain date http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/07/29/programatically-deleting-older-blobs-in-windows-azure-storage.aspx

Obviously very simple to do change it to get blobs newer than a certain date.

Comment: According to the azure docs this now won't work - conditional headers can't be used on ListBlobs operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Specifying-Conditional-Headers-for-Blob-Service-Operations?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Subheading2

Answer (score 0):

You can do a client side filter to get the data you want.  So pull down the blobs and then filter them in code (using Linq or whatever you like) before surfacing the results.

Comment: Yeah I was planning do that as my last option but still curious to know why the AccessCondition doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is keep an Storage Table with a list of the files.  Use that as an index to find those you care about by filtering on the table.  I have done with some code, but I was also totally in control of what is being written to the storage account (only my app does).  So it wasn't too bad to implement.